# BluePy Frequent BLE Disconnects between Raspberry Pi4 and ESP32 - (Bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian, esp32

I (like others) have multiple disconnects between a RPi4 central(client) and ESP32 BLE peripheral(server). Using the "nRF Connect" app on a android phone, the connection to the ESP32 is robust. However, RPi4 - ESP32 BLE communication is VERY unstable. This finding implies the fault is with the RPi and/or code. The initial BLE connection occurs faithfully but the connection inevitably drops after a random number of successful reads (usually 1-50 reads). I am using BluePy 1.3.0 with a new Raspbian image on a RPI4. I attached skeleton code and the error message produced after a random number of successful Reads.

```
    import time
    from bluepy.btle import Peripheral

    peripheral_address = "8c:aa:b5:85:20:1e"
    service_uuid =  "537e7010-9928-4595-89dc-46b495862dc6"
    characteristic_uuid = "3778ceab-0974-4eb0-9da5-26c3a69cc742" # Read from peripheral

    p = Peripheral(peripheral_address, "public") #random does not work!!
    Service=p.getServiceByUUID(service_uuid)
    Characterization=Service.getCharacteristics(characteristic_uuid)[0]
    print("Got characterization")

    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        value = Characterization.read()
        print(value)
        time.sleep(0.1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/BLETest/bleRead.py", line 16, in <module>
    value = Characterization.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 197, in read
    return self.peripheral.readCharacteristic(self.valHandle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 530, in readCharacteristic
    resp = self._getResp('rd')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 407, in _getResp
    resp = self._waitResp(wantType + ['ntfy', 'ind'], timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 362, in _waitResp
    raise BTLEDisconnectError("Device disconnected", resp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Device disconnected
```

Note: Adding code to catch the disconnect exception has been unsuccessful thus far resulting in additional raised errors and loss of data secondary to the time it takes to reconnect.

I am very interested to hear from anyone who has robust BLE communication with a RPi client? Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of things it could be but there a couple areas that I would investigate.

Firstly there is a bit churn going on with Bluetooth firmware on the RPi at the moment as you can see from this thread:
https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/issues/8

So I would check that you are [up to date](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) with with those.

BluePy I believe has a `bluepy-helper` module which is based on Bluez version 5.47 which is behind what the RPi is using now. Might be worth trying a different library to see if the issue persists.

Here is an example of reading your characteristic with the BlueZ D-Bus API directly using [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) for the python D-Bus bindings:

```py
from time import sleep
import pydbus
from gi.repository import GLib

peripheral_address = "8C:AA:B5:85:20:1E"
service_uuid =  "537e7010-9928-4595-89dc-46b495862dc6"
characteristic_uuid = "3778ceab-0974-4eb0-9da5-26c3a69cc742" # Read from peripheral

# DBus object paths
BLUEZ_SERVICE = 'org.bluez'
ADAPTER_PATH = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{ADAPTER_PATH}/dev_{peripheral_address.replace(':', '_')}"

# setup dbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, '/')
adapter = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, ADAPTER_PATH) 
device = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, device_path)

device.Connect()

while not device.ServicesResolved:
    sleep(0.5)

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    """Look up DBus path for characteristic UUID"""
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid.casefold():
           return path

# Characteristic DBus information
char_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, characteristic_uuid)
characterization = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, char_path)

# Read characteristic without event loop notifications
while True:
    print(characterization.ReadValue({}))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Does the characteristic you are reading from support notifications? If it does then that is a more efficient way to use the Bluetooth link. The above `while` loop can be replaced with:

```py
# Enable eventloop for notifications
def notify_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    """Notify event handler for characteristic"""
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
        new_value = prop_changed['Value']
        print(f"Received: {new_value}")


mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
characterization.onPropertiesChanged = notify_handler
characterization.StartNotify()
try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mainloop.quit()
    characterization.StopNotify()
    device.Disconnect()
```

Comment: I tried running your code but get error in line 20 device = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, device_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 59, in get
    return CompositeInterface(introspection)(self, bus_name, object_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 118, in CompositeInterface
    raise KeyError("object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()")
KeyError: 'object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'

Comment: I think the address might need to be in uppercase so I've updated my answer. You can see what the device path should be by using the following command line tool `busctl tree org.bluez`

Comment: The characteristic has read and notify properties enabled. But after replacing the code as suggested to use notifications characterization.StartNotify() throws GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NotSupported: Operation is not supported (36). I'm stumped...again! :(

Comment: No. Same error after acquire-write command. But peripheral works with nRF Connect android app client.

Comment: `acquire-write` doesn't sound like the correct command. Can you update your question with the `bluetoothctl` transcript? I would expect the sequence of commands in `bluetoothctl` to be `connect <your device address>`, `menu gatt`, `list-attributes`, `select-attribute <path of attribute from previous command>`, `attribute-info`, and finally `notify on`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have given up on the RPI and moved my project to a ESP32.

Answer (score 2):

Recently,I have also met the same problem with you. But Just now I may solved this problem.I test two kinds of Bluetooth Low libs on raspberry 4 .One of them is [bluepy](https://github.com/orientlu/bluepy), the other is [bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak).

At first, I just ran codes with above two libs on raspberry 4, which had a older raspios.
Besides I once disabled bluetooth on it, Because I had to use its UART to communicate.
The codes did not work. It failed with disconnected problem or hung with no reaction.

When I have no ideas about these problems, I downloaded ['Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software'](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit). I Burned the OS within SD card, insertd it to the Raspberry 4 and debugged the codes of two above libs. They runned properly. I can receive notification data continuously without any exceptions.

So, I think these problems is due to some conflicts between Bluetooth-low-energy and UART.
Though I remove lines in OS's config.txt, which I did to disbled ble and use [uart](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-uarts). The OS may not back to the original status, or I forgot some other operations I have did. Because I am a beginner to know this kind OS.

That's all what I have did. I also insert the SD Card in Raspberry 3 B+. It also works.

Hopefully this is helpful to you.